# Reading Azure directory roles (built in roles) via Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there any way to see which Azure directory roles (built-in roles) a user is assigned to?

I need the information we get when we find the user and go to "Assigned Roles".
I've tried to find some commands in the Azure documentation however without success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have [graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to list all the built-in roles. So that we could know it's a directory object as well.

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles

So we could search in the user methods and find that we have [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) `MemberOf` to give us the diretory objects the user belongs to.

[image]

Using API like below could give us the properties.

> Get
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id?$expand=memberOf($select=displayName,id)

[image]

It proved that memberof is what we need to get, and we just need to add a filter to get all the directory roles. So here's the API I found.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/user_id/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.directoryRole

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using PowerShell and the [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0). See the example below.

```
$tenant = "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com";
$disconnectGraphAfterExecution = $true;


Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.Read.All,RoleManagement.Read.All -TenantId $tenant -NoWelcome;


$portalUsers = Get-MgBetaUser -all -filter "creationType eq 'Invitation'";


foreach ($portalUser in $portalUsers) {
    $directoryRolesForUser = "";
    Get-MgBetaUserMemberOfAsDirectoryRole -UserId $user.Id | ForEach-Object { $directoryRolesForUser += $_.DisplayName + ", "; };

    $directoryRolesForUser = $string.TrimEnd(', ');

    $portalUsers | Add-Member "DirectoryRoles" $directoryRolesForUser -Force;
}

$portalUsers | Select-Object Id, DisplayName, mail, CreationType, ExternalUserState, DirectoryRoles | fl;

if ($disconnectGraphAfterExecution) { Disconnect-MgGraph; };
```